# ee.mapclient with python 2.7 and Anaconda, possible alternatives?

Tags: python-2.7, google-earth-engine

I have installed the google earth engine python APIs in my MAcOS where also Anaconda is installed. I got problem with the object ee.mapclient. I made it working modifying the line of the import using

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

Now it does not produce error message but it is not working either. When I run a script in Spyder the console returns several message and it enters in loop.
Running the same script line by line in the console, a big black window is opened but nothing is displayed.

Is there any solution to make it working? I know that the developer is not maintaining this object because too dependent to TK libraries. Is there any other solution to display satellite data?